# PHP: Get value from array

Tags: php, arrays, json, var-dump

I am using the bukkit JSONAPI and php JSONAPI.php to get the list of players on my minecraft server to my website. To get the count, I do this:

```
require('JSONAPI.php'); // get this file at:      https://github.com/alecgorge/jsonapi/raw/master/sdk/php/JSONAPI.php

$api = new JSONAPI("localhost", 20059, "user", "pass", "salt");

$limit = $api->call("getPlayerLimit");
$count = $api->call("getPlayerCount");

$c = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_PORT, 20059);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$result = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
echo "<h5>Players online:</h5>";
$num= '' . $count['success'] . '/' . $limit['success'];
echo $num;
```

This returns: 1/40
Then, I try to get the player list:

```
$list = $api->call('getPlayerNames');
echo $list;
```

This just returns: Array
However, when I do

```
var_dump($api->call('getPlayerNames'));
```

I get:

```
array(3) { ["result"]=> string(7) "success" ["source"]=> string(14) "getPlayerNames" ["success"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "gauso001" } }
```

However, what I want is simply a list of the players without all of the extra stuff. Sorry if this is a noob question, I only know pretty basic PHP.

Stuff that might help: 
method docs: http://alecgorge.com/minecraft/jsonapi/apidocs/#package-JSONAPI%20standard
tell me what else..

THANK YOU in advance, I hope I'll be as good as you in PHP one day :D

Comment: As you show with the var_dump, the return from the api call method is an array, with three elements.  You want the contents of the 'success' element, which appears to be an array.  You haven't specified how you'd like the names if there's more than one, but that would likely involve iterating over the returned array . . . show us some sample code, and we can go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$api->call('getPlayerNames')` returns a named array, one key of which (`success`) is another array containing the player names. Iterate over the `success` key to get the player list.

```
$players = $api->call('getPlayerNames');
foreach($players['success'] as $player) {
    echo $player;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like player names, oddly enough, are contained as an array in the `success` key.

To access the player names, you could:

```
$list = $api->call('getPlayerNames');
// debug
print_r($list['success']);
// direct access
echo $list['success'][0];
// loop
foreach($list['success'] as $player) {
    echo $player;
}
```

Format to your needs. But that should get you started.

**Note:** I'd also encourage you to learn about [Arrays in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).